# Quadratic Variation of Stochastic Integral of Simple Predictable process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

Take $H\in S$ to be a *simple process* defined as:
$$H_t:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} H_i1_{(T_i,T_{i+1}]}(t),\ \  H_i\in \mathcal{F}_{T_i}, \ (T_1\leq...\leq T_n \ stopping\  times),$$

and $X$ a Good Integrator.
The Stochastic Integral $(H\cdot X)$ of $H$ w.r.t. $X$  is defined as:

$$(H\cdot X)_t:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} H_i(X_t^{T_{i+1}} - X_t^{T_i}).$$

I want to prove that:

$$[(H\cdot X),(H\cdot X)]=(H^2\cdot [X,X]),$$

where $[Y,Y]$ is the quadratic variation of the process $Y$, defined as:
$$[X,X]:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_t^{T_{i+1}} - X_t^{T_i})^2 .$$

I worked out the following but I am not sure it is correct:

First note: $(H\cdot X)_{T_{i+1}\wedge t}-(H\cdot X)_{T_i\wedge t} =H_i(X_{T_{i+1}\wedge t} - X_{T_{i}\wedge t})$,

then: $$[(H\cdot X),(H\cdot X)]_t=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ((H\cdot X)_t^{T_{i+1}} - (H\cdot X)_t^{T_i})^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} H_i^2(X_{T_{i+1}\wedge t} - X_{T_{i}\wedge t})^2=$$
$$=(H^2\cdot [X,X])_t$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Why does the last "$=$" hold?

Comment: @saz that is what I do not know

Comment: I see. Since you have a very particular question (the one about last equality), why not ask this question instead of asking "Is this reasoning correct"? Because, actually, your reasoning *is* correct (in the sense that all the "=" hold true), but this doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @saz I asked it in this way because I know I have to show I actually worked on it

Comment: yeah, that's great; my point is simply that it is easier to answer your question if you make clear where you have doubts (e.g. ask "I'm not sure why the last equality holds" instead of "Is this reasoning correct"). Anyway: Are you sure that the stated definition of the quadratic variation process is correct? Usually, there are partitions involved and the mesh size of the partitions go to $0$...

Comment: you could also check [theorem 7](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/properties-of-quadratic-variations/#scn_qvprop_thm7) from Tao's blog, to get an impression how he proceeds (it is similar to yours); another remark, you should be careful while defining your stochastic integral for a simple process to use two times the same Variable $H$, for the integral process and for the simple function's coefficient